# error: ORA-02289 - Sequence doesn't exist in Agile PLM 9.3.5

Tags: sqlplus, oracle-agile-plm

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. 
I am facing issues while performing any action in Agile PLM 9.3.5. I have upgraded PLM from 9.3.3 to 9.3.5. Checked in Sequence table also, all the sequences are available.Still, getting the above error while creating any Object or updating any user profile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to resolve the issue if it's still not resolved:

After you upgraded to Agile 9.3.5, You need to run 'reorder_query.bat' shell script in the [AUT_HOME]/AUT/bin directory. This tool clears out temporary records and gaps to compact the query table to reuse sequence IDs. This information is in the Agile Database Upgrade Guide.

If that doesn't work, please refer to Doc ID 1606365.1 in MOS KB.

Else, if you don't have access, I am copy pasting the excerpt below about the plan of action.

1. Stop application server and bounce the database server to make sure all inflight transactions are committed.  While the database is down, take a cold backup.  Leave the application server down during this process to prevent users from connecting.
2. Download the attached script called GAP_HUNTER_GC_v1.0.sql to a machine that has Oracle database client installed and can connect to your Agile schema through SQL*Plus, and run it.  For example, the output on the screen will look similar to this:

   ```
   SQL> @GAP_HUNTER_GC_v1.0.sql

   You are logging on DB User - AGILE
   Your agile database data version is 9.3.095.0
   Your agile database schema version is 9.3.095

   Please enter the gap threshold, default 5000:
   Please enter the number of top largest gaps, default 10:
   >>>>>>>> Start to collect gap ....
   >>>>>>>> Prepare for scanning tables....
   >>>>>>>> Start to collect tables and Generate the mapping tables ....
   >>>>>>>> Step 1: Collect Reused ids....Begin time:20131208 11:39:17
   table is not existing:Regulation_addorreplace_action
   table is not existing:Regulation_addorreplace_task
   table is not existing:INSTANCES
   table is not existing:REFERENCE_OBJECT
   >>>>>>>> Step 2: Generate gap .... Begin time:20131208 11:39:17
   >>>>>>>> Step 3: Finish the Gap Hunter Process ....
   >>>>>>>> Report: There are 0 id(s) have been collected in the GAP
     Sequence Indexer Number,                 Gap Size,          Starting Number,            Ending Number
                    67018473,                131226320,               1352956646,               1484182965
                    50955717,                 94058060,               1031324895,               1125382954
                    89993219,                 87600000,               1812982965,               1900582964
                    78036370,                 87424300,               1573458652,               1660882951
                    29531387,                 77700000,                601882965,                679582964
                    86572585,                 68412680,               1744470274,               1812882953
                    59910085,                 67800000,               1210682962,               1278482961
                    25834330,                 59801320,                527781692,                587583011
                    83797585,                 55500000,               1688882958,               1744382957
                    12104050,                 47011460,                252171585,                299183044
   >>>>>>>> End .........
   ```
3. The output from step 2 is placed into log files on the file system.  The log files are located in the same directory where SQL*Plus was launched from.  Look for the following files:

   ```
   gap_hunter_version.log
   gap_hunter.log
   gap_hunter_report.log
   ```
4. Open the gap_hunter_report.log file and review the first set of numbers in the list.  For example:

   ```
   Sequence Indexer Number,                 Gap Size,          Starting Number,            Ending Number
                  67018473,                131226320,               1352956646,               1484182965
   ```

   This indicates the largest set of number available with a gap size of 131226320, starting with 1352956646 and ending with 1484182965.
5. Drop and recreate the AGILEOBJECTIDSEQUENCE sequence using the numbers in step 4:

   ```
   drop sequence AGILEOBJECTIDSEQUENCE;
   create sequence AGILEOBJECTIDSEQUENCE minvalue 1 maxvalue [Ending Number] increment by 20 cache 20 noorder nocycle start with [Starting Number];
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   SQL> drop sequence AGILEOBJECTIDSEQUENCE;

   Sequence dropped.

   SQL> create sequence AGILEOBJECTIDSEQUENCE minvalue 1 maxvalue 1484182965 increment by 20 cache 20 noorder nocycle start with 1352956646;

   Sequence created.
   ```